# CSS 3D animation not working correctly in IE11

Tags: css, animation, 3d, internet-explorer-11

This animation does not behave as I'd expect it to in IE11.

It should open like a book.

It was created in [Google Web Designer](http://www.google.co.uk/webdesigner/) (omitted large portions of the code for brevity).

[JSFiddle (open in IE11)](http://jsfiddle.net/e45q5/)

However the following DOES work in Chrome (only difference is I've included the WebKit prefixes).

[JSFiddle (open in Chrome)](http://jsfiddle.net/qSQYS/)

Points of interest:

```
@keyframes mykeyframes {
      0% { transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 2px); }
      100% { transform: matrix3d(-0.9998476952, 0, 0.0174524064, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0174524064, 0, -0.9998476952, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1); }
    }
```

**Update**
Just noticed that if you don't animate it "fully" (so it only swings open part way) then it works fine in IE11 - http://jsfiddle.net/e45q5/3/

**Update2**
I believe it's related to this bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/gwdbeta/gwdbeta/EOKnHw5qXmk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to debug a `matrix3d` value, but I can emulate the effect by editing your animation:

```
 @keyframes mykeyframes {
      0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e45q5/2/

Comment: That's great. I'd like to know why it doesn't work with `matrix3d`, as that's what Google Web Designer automatically produces.